# How to register and retrieve roles with privileges in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning spring boot. In my sample app, I have to provide role based authorisation and authentication. I have managed to set roles, but manually in database and access it.
Now what I need to do is also use privilege like read write. My design is many to many mapping between user and role, and many to many mapping between role and privileges.
What I don't know is how to register this part user.setRoles(and set privileges along with). And how to check those privileges along with roles in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ie `.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/people").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN").mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/people").hasRole("ADMIN")`

While I know it has get authority method but I am not able to register and use it properly.

Here is my code

```
package com.zen.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity

public class Admin implements Serializable {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long adminid;

    public Long getId() {
        return adminid;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.adminid = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
    public boolean isTokenExpired() {
        return tokenExpired;
    }
    public void setTokenExpired(boolean tokenExpired) {
        this.tokenExpired = tokenExpired;
    }
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;  
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean tokenExpired;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="user_role",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="admin_id",referencedColumnName = "adminid"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "role_id",referencedColumnName = "rid"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}

package com.zen.model;



import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

@Entity
//@Table(name = "role")
//@Scope("prototype")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority,Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int getEid() {
        return rid;
    }
    public void setEid(int eid) {
        this.rid = eid;
    }
//  public String getType() {
//      return name;
//  }
//  public void setType(String type) {
//      this.name = type;
//  }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int rid=1;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<SuperAdmin> superAdmin;
    
    public Set<SuperAdmin> getSuperAdmin() {
        return superAdmin;
    }
    public void setSuperAdmin(Set<SuperAdmin> superAdmin) {
        this.superAdmin = superAdmin;
    }
    public Set<Admin> getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }
    public void setAdmin(Set<Admin> admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Admin> admin;
    
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    private String name;
    
    
    
     @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="role_privileges",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="rid",referencedColumnName = "rid"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name= "privilege_id"))
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;
    public Set<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }
    public void setPrivileges(Set<Privilege> privileges) {
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("authority");
        System.out.print(name);
        return name;
    }
}

    package com.zen.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Privilege implements Serializable {
 
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 752219249055564923L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long privilege_id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

So how to set them and get them in UserDetailService ?
Thank you :)

Comment: Spring security doesn't really have the concept of `privileges` instead authorization is built upon a `Voting system` where voters will vote on granting access or not. thats why for instance all roles need the prefix `ROLE_` because there is a specific voter that triggers on that prefix. I suggest you read the section of the Spring Security documentation that deals with the `Pre invocation handling Step` which might lead you in on on the path of what you are seeking. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authz-arch

Comment: @Toerktumlare I think you misunderstood the question, I need to implement roles with authority, for example admin with read or write, I am able to perform role based, but how to additionally add privileges with roles was the question.

Comment: i think you did not read my answer, so i will have to repeat myself. Spring security does not have the concept of privileges, it has a voter system which means that you need to read the sections i posted and create authorities like `WRITE_ADMIN` or hierarchical roles like `FULL_ADMIN > WRITE_ADMIN, READ_ADMIN` etc. Please read the chapter i posted, before you add another comment.

Comment: @Toerktumlare can you please explain what is being done here ? https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration I need to implement this. Somewhere I saw they are using getauthorities with getroles.

Comment: all they have done there is that in the database they have a table containing roles. Each Role has a `OneToMany` relationship to a table which has what they call `Privileges`. When they create the principal, they fetch the `Role` from the database, then through that role they fetch all relational `Privileges`. Then they take each `Privilege` and create a `Spring Granted Authority (a spring role)`.

So as i said before, Spring has no concept of `privileges` instead what they have done in that tutorial is to just subgroup roles in the database, fetch them and then build regular spring roles.

Comment: @Toerktumlare but can you tell me how to fetch that separately in security config ? I am getting some error if I use their method. get roles return null How to use something like has(role_admin) and hasAuhtority(Read) for one admin user and read write for other. has authority is not able to check it somehow.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a coding forum, its a Q/A site, here we answer single well defined questions. This has already derailed into a discussion. My advice to you is start googling, reading up. All question you have asked has answers in the spring docs. You don’t ask thing here to avoid reading the documentation. If you have problems then post a question with code proper errors, debug logs etc. You meed to do a lot more research. If you get an error the LEARN about the error.